# Allowing remote access to PHPMyAdmin in Windows

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp, remote-access

I am trying to set up remote access for trusted partner to my local server. I am using phpmyadmin inside XAMPP. I try to follow the link below:

https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/91893-allowing-remote-access-to-phpmyadmin

But I cannot find phpMyAdmin.conf. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 4):

If you see below error message on WINDOWS, when trying to access phpMyAdmin from another IP other than *localhost/127.0.0.1*:

***New XAMPP security concept:***

***Access to the requested directory is only available from the local network.***

***This setting can be configured in the file "httpd-xampp.conf".***

open httpd-xammp.conf file from XAMPP control panel by clicking on the **config** tab

You can do next (for XAMPP, deployed on the UNIX-system): You can try changing the configuration for the following lines of configuration

```
<Directory "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin">
    AllowOverride AuthConfig
    Require local
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</Directory>
```

**TO**

```
<Directory "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin">
    AllowOverride AuthConfig
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
    #Require local
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</Directory>
```

**Kindly restart apache server after all configuration for it to take effect.**

Now you can access http://[server_ip]/phpmyadmin/